# Unable to get property 'target' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angularjs

I have this in controller :

```
 $scope.SearchOnEnter = function (event) {
            var element = angular.element(event.target);
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                _search(element.val());
            }

        }
```

In html i have this:

```
 <input type="search" data-ng-model="searchText" data-ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" placeholder="@Translator.Translate("SEARCH_OFFER")" data-ng-keydown="checkKeyDown($event);SearchPOnEnter($event)" data-ng-change="search()" data-ng-enter="SearchOnEnter(searchText)" />
```

But in console im geting error:

> Unable to get property 'target' of undefined or null reference

Comment: you can't do this without using a controller or parent scope `data-ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" `

Comment: @atinder what u mean by that?

Comment: there is more than 1 thing wrong. create a plunkr of fiddle first.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16775/ there is fiddle but here is not working now :S

Answer (score 1):

Check this demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16803/).

It simply works as expected. Your JSFiddle doesn't work because you do not import AngularJS correctly. Also need to add `ng-app="myApp"`:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing searchText to the function:

```
data-ng-enter="SearchOnEnter(searchText)"
```

but in the function expect it to be an event.

I guess you meant it to be

```
data-ng-enter="SearchOnEnter($event)"
```